# Optimization metric in Generative Adversarial Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

The [paper on GANs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661v1.pdf) contains the following excerpt:

> Early in learning, when $G$ is poor, $D$ can reject samples
>   with high confidence because they are clearly different from the
>   training data. In this case, $\log(1 − D(G(z)))$ saturates. Rather than
>   training $G$ to minimize $\log(1 − D(G(z)))$ we can train $G$ to maximize $\log D(G(z))$. This objective function results in the same fixed point of
>   the dynamics of $G$ and $D$ but provides much stronger gradients early in
>   learning.

I was hoping for some clarification on why using the new metric fixes the saturation problem. Doesn't the exact same problem still exist? $G$ is poor so $D$ can *still* reject samples with a high confidence because they are clearly different from the training data.

Answer (score 1):

Let us have a look at the log function's graph. As you can see below, the function `log(x)` becomes `0` when `x=1` and is negative between 0 and 1. Notice that the function increases steeply(high value of slope) as you move from 0 to 1 and the rate of growth(slope) decreases thereafter.

[image: Graph of the log function]

$D(x)$ represents the probability that `x` came from the data rather than being generated by `G`. At the start of training, the generator is producing random data which is clearly different from the original data distribution. The discriminator can identify this easily and hence $D(G(z))$ is very close to 0 (discriminator having high confidence that this is fake). If we use $\log(1 − D(G(z)))$ in the objective function, then this value is close to 0 i.e. `log(1)` and hence there won't be a strong gradient propagating to the generator. On the other hand, $\log D(G(z))$ will have very high absolute values(see the graph) and hence provide a strong gradient update. As training progresses and $\log D(G(z))$ gets closer to 0.5 the size of gradient update reduces just as we would want it to be. The saturation problem is fixed because the `log(x)` values for numbers closer to 0 change much more sharply than for numbers closer to 1.